# Google Maps V2 Android works as fragment, but shows white screen (with zoom control) as child fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I've been researching this problem for a couple days and have tried everything offered by SO with no success.

When I follow instructions outlined by Google [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api), I have no problems getting a general Google Map displayed in a custom Map Fragment (`QMapFragment`) that extends SupportMapFragment under my FragmentActivity.

(Side Note: Even if I provide a dummy API Key, e.g., "abcd", in the Manifest.xml, the map is still displayed just fine.  I'm confused by that, but anyway...)

But when I add `QMapFragment` as a child fragment to another custom Fragment, e.g., with the following code:

```
mFrag = QMapFragment.newInstance(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

transaction.add(R.id.framelayout, mFrag).commit();
```

I see a blank screen with zoom controls being added to the fragment, and I get this in LogCat

```
08-08 13:44:25.914: W/dalvikvm(7057): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 30
08-08 13:44:25.914: D/dalvikvm(7057): VFY: replacing opcode 0x52 at 0x0012
08-08 13:44:25.914: D/dalvikvm(7057): VFY: dead code 0x0014-0018 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.b (Landroid/content/res/Resources;)Z
08-08 13:44:26.000: I/dalvikvm(7057): Total arena pages for JIT: 11
08-08 13:44:26.180: W/dalvikvm(7057): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/p/w; (734)
08-08 13:44:26.180: W/dalvikvm(7057): Link of class 'Lmaps/p/w;' failed
08-08 13:44:26.180: W/dalvikvm(7057): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/ap/as; (6056)
08-08 13:44:26.180: W/dalvikvm(7057): Link of class 'Lmaps/ap/as;' failed
08-08 13:44:26.180: W/dalvikvm(7057): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/af/k; (5085)
08-08 13:44:26.180: W/dalvikvm(7057): Link of class 'Lmaps/af/k;' failed
08-08 13:44:26.187: E/dalvikvm(7057): Could not find class 'maps.af.k', referenced from method maps.ag.an.a
08-08 13:44:26.187: W/dalvikvm(7057): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4928 (Lmaps/af/k;) in Lmaps/ag/an;
```

[Screenshot of properties](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1143616/Screen%20Shot%202013-08-08%20at%201.46.06%20PM.png)

And no, I don't get an "Authorization Failed" from the debugger, and my console is set to Google Android v2 on Google API.

Comment: That's very strange. If you can make a reproducible test case, you might consider filing an issue at http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list Also note that your project does not need the Google APIs -- that's for Maps V1.

Comment: Always completely uninstall and re-install your app if you run into these kinds of issues. I also noticed that API key caching under certain conditions. Invalid API keys resulting in a map being displayed just fine, and valid API keys resulting in a map not being displayed : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtWWt2blDTg&feature=c4-overview&list=UU5IDcgLgmrgRhAoTsPk7KpQ

Comment: What happens if you replace `QMapFragment.newInstance(...)` with `SupportMapFragment.newInstance()`?

Comment: Side Note: using dummy API key is causing no problems, because the first key check is cached. A bad implementation I would say, so always uninstall the app and install again when in doubt (like ddewaele said).

Comment: Thx for the link re caching.  I confirm that if I delete and reinstall with the dummy key, the logs show: 08-08 15:12:29.617: E/Google Maps Android API(14333): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

I've put in the correct API key and it works, so we can rule out it being an API key issue.  

@MaciejGórski The same behavior and error logs are displayed when I use SupportMapFragment.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having the same issue when using transaction.add. From then on one of my base rules was to never user transaction.add again and use transaction.replace instead.
Try it, it should work.

Comment: I had already tried using replace instead.  The same behavior occurred.  In fact, the original fragment was still being displayed despite the replace.  

I've since stopped trying to include the full Google maps and have turned to just using [Google's static map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)